# connection tab does not appear

Tags: oracle, connection, oracle-sqldeveloper, database-connection

I installed Oracle SQL Developer. But when i want to create a connection , the tabs does not appear. I tried all the ways but none of them worked. Could you please direct me or give me an advice.

thank you in advance

i reset the factory settings